# How to handle state changes in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building a company/department/user selector.

[image]

When the user selects the company, the app needs to fetch that company's departments and users, and update the select lists.

Right now I have a `companies` collection, `departments` collection, and a `users` collection, which hold their respective models.

When a user selects a company, what is the best way to update my app?

### Option 1

1. The CompanyView fires a `userSet:company` event, sending out the id of company along with it.
2. `companies` hears `userSet:company` and updates its `selected` property with the id from the event.
3. `departments`

   - hears `userSet:company` and updates its `url` property based on the company id from the event
   - fetches based on this new url
   - on success, notifies `DepartmentView` it has changed by firing a `changed:departments` event
4. `users`

   - hears `userSet:company` and updates its url proprty based on the company id
   - fetches based on this new url
   - on success, notifies `UserView` it has changed by firing a `changed:users` event

If I go with this option, both `departments` and `users` will have a custom fetch event that looks something like

```
fetchAndTrigger: function(event) {
    this.url = 'http://'+document.location.host+'/data/companies/'+event.get('id')+'/departments';
    this.fetch({
        success: function() {
            events.trigger("changed:departments");
        }
    });
}
```

This seems problematic to me, because even though my views can be generated directly from the models/collections, the collections don't know how to `fetch` unless they have the event (i.e. they aren't fully saving the state of the application).

### Option 2

The main difference here is in step 1:

1. The CompanyView updates the `selected` property of the `companies` collection. It then fires a `userSet:company` event.

Then, the `departments` and `users` collections can look at the `companies` collection to get their urls:

```
// departments collection
url: function() {
    return 'http://'+document.location.host+'/data/companies/'+this.companies.selected.id+'/departments';
}
```

Now I can call `fetch` directly, and just worry about the success handler.

The problem I see here is that now my collections have to know about each other. As this is only the tip of the app, I know it will get harder to maintain, especially as I have to deal with async. callbacks (i.e. if they start listening to each other's `changed:department` events things will get too complex).

### Option 3

I could look into routes, and on each UI change update the route, then update my models from there. It seems like having state in my models will give me more flexibility in the future, but I'm brand new to Backbone/client-side MVC so I could be wrong on this.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

There is schematic workflow. Hope this will help you.

```
HTML:
     <select data-company></select>
     <select data-department></select>
     <select data-user></select>

Initialization :
     new View({departments:new Departments(), users:new Users()});

Collections :
     setId (id) :
          this.url = 'http://location/' + id + '/resource';
          return this;

View :
     initialize :
          this.listenTo(this.options.departments, 'sync', this.renderDepartments);
          this.listenTo(this.options.users, 'sync', this.renderUsers);

     events :
          'change [data-company]' : 'companyChangeHandler'
          'change [data-department]' : 'departmentChangeHandler'

     companyChangeHandler (e) :
          this.$('[data-department]').empty();
          this.$('[data-user]').empty();
          this.options.departments.setId(e.currentTarget.value).fetch();

     departmentChangeHandler (e) :
          this.$('[data-user]').empty(); 
          this.options.users.setId(e.currentTarget.value).fetch();

     renderDepartments :
          // append options to this.$('[data-department]');  

     renderUsers :
          // append options to this.$('[data-user]');
```